# phpinfo shows difference between Local and Master Values of default_charset

Tags: ubuntu, charset, defaults, phpinfo

Here us there is a difference in the `local default_charset` than the `master's`.  Is there a way to find the source of the change of each? Especially the local?  So it shows the path of the file that is changing that value?

My server details are: *PHP Version 5.6.39-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PHP automatically sets the charset of the file it is executing. So first I would check the encoding of your files.

With Linux: `find . -exec file {} \;`

If you suspect that some code sets it, search for `ini_set('default_charset',...)`